# Legendre symbol in theory of numbers

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fractions

How can I get a Legendre symbol

[image: example],

which just used the dashed line instead of the fractional rule?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\legendre@dash#1#2{\hb@xt@#1{%
  \kern-#2\p@
  \cleaders\hbox{\kern.5\p@
    \vrule\@height.2\p@\@depth.2\p@\@width\p@
    \kern.5\p@}\hfil
  \kern-#2\p@
  }}
\def\@legendre#1#2#3#4#5{\mathopen{}\left(
  \sbox\z@{$\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{#1}{#3#4}{#3#5}$}%
  \dimen@=\wd\z@
  \kern-\p@\vcenter{\box0}\kern-\dimen@\vcenter{\legendre@dash\dimen@{#2}}\kern-\p@
  \right)\mathclose{}}
\newcommand\legendre[2]{\mathchoice
  {\@legendre{0}{1}{}{#1}{#2}}
  {\@legendre{1}{.5}{\vphantom{1}}{#1}{#2}}
  {\@legendre{2}{0}{\vphantom{1}}{#1}{#2}}
  {\@legendre{3}{0}{\vphantom{1}}{#1}{#2}}
}
\def\dlegendre{\@legendre{0}{1}{}}
\def\tlegendre{\@legendre{1}{0.5}{\vphantom{1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\genfrac(){}{0}{a}{b}$

$\dlegendre{a}{b}\dlegendre{10}{20}$

$\genfrac(){}{}{a}{b}\legendre{a}{b}\legendre{100}{200}$

$\scriptstyle\genfrac(){}{}{a}{b}\legendre{a}{b}\legendre{10}{20}$

$\scriptscriptstyle\genfrac(){}{}{a}{b}\legendre{a}{b}\legendre{10}{20}$

$\displaystyle\legendre{a}{b}\textstyle\legendre{a}{b}
  \scriptstyle\legendre{a}{b}\scriptscriptstyle\legendre{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

The user command are `\legendre` that typesets the symbol in the current math style or `\dlegendre` and `\tlegendre` to force display or text style.

[image]

The `\genfrac` parts are only for comparisons.

Comment: The $\genfrac(){}{}{p}{q}\legendre{p}{q}$ get a  bit of larger parenthese.

Comment: @fas: I've edited the macros.

Comment: @fas: I should add that I've seen nowhere this notation.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting question. My first idea was to write In french the symbol is

```
$\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)$
```

but without dashed line, the second idea was to use `\genfrac` but I don't know how to draw the dashed line so  the last idea is to use `arydshln`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,arydshln} 

\def\Legendre(#1,#2){%
\begin{pmatrix}
#1\cr 
\hdashline[1pt/1pt]
#2\cr
\end{pmatrix}}  

\begin{document}
$\Legendre(97,37)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking at the code, `\genfrac` uses `\over` (or `\above`) internally so the line is produced by a primitive and thus I don't think one could *easily* modify `\genfrac` to produce a dashed line.  Shame.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this type of notation a lot, I am not sure if the following is suitable but at least, it is quite simple to get some automation wrapped around it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\lege}[2]{\ensuremath{%
\begin{aligned}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (lege) at (0,0) {
#1  \\
#2  \\
};
\draw[densely dashed] (lege.west) -- (lege.east);
\end{tikzpicture}\end{aligned}}%
}


\begin{document}
\[ \lege{1252}{567}\lege{1}{0} \int^\infty_0{dx}\]    
\end{document}
```

[image: Trying out the code]

I can't foresee any problems with my code but I can sense that there are. Hence, I am pretty sure that advanced users here would find a smarter way to do it (especially the spacing of the delimiters with `xshift` etc.). You can scale the whole `tikzpicture` to get different sizes. Cheers.